# Converting from XNA3.1 to XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, xna-3.0

How to convert this code part from XNA 3.1 to XNA 4.0.
If someone knows please help.

```cs
public ModelLightMesh(Viewer3D viewer, Vector3 position, float radius, Color color, float u0, float v0, float u1, float v1)
    {
        var verticies = new[] {
            new VertexPositionColorTexture(new Vector3(position.X - radius, position.Y + radius, position.Z), color, new Vector2(u1, v0)),
            new VertexPositionColorTexture(new Vector3(position.X + radius, position.Y + radius, position.Z), color, new Vector2(u0, v0)),
            new VertexPositionColorTexture(new Vector3(position.X + radius, position.Y - radius, position.Z), color, new Vector2(u0, v1)),
            new VertexPositionColorTexture(new Vector3(position.X - radius, position.Y - radius, position.Z), color, new Vector2(u1, v1)),
        };
        VertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration(viewer.GraphicsDevice, VertexPositionColorTexture.VertexElements);
        VertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(viewer.GraphicsDevice, VertexPositionColorTexture.SizeInBytes * verticies.Length, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
        VertexBuffer.SetData(verticies);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft highlighted the differences in a series of MSDN articles along with code examples.

You can also use the cheat sheet provided here:

http://nelxon.com/resources/xna-3-1-to-xna-4-0-cheatsheet.php

**Articles**:

- [Converting a 3D XNA 3.0 game to XNA 4.0 – an example](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/grozen/archive/2010/10/23/converting-a-3d-xna-3-0-game-to-xna-4-0-an-example.aspx)
- [XNA Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/centrum-xna.aspx)

PS: Your answer may have been downvoted, because you didn't specifically run into trouble and asked about concrete issues?

Comment: @Tasleem, I added links from the top of my bookmark-list. List your errors, and I will help you.

Comment: The cheatsheet has moved to http://www.nelsonhurst.com/xna-3-1-to-xna-4-0-cheatsheet/